# Foundation 6 drilldown menu: add back event to custom button

Tags: zurb-foundation, customization, drilldown

The default `js-drilldown-back` button is not the way I like it.
Instead of having an entire li element for the back functionality I would like to trigger the back event on a custom element.

How to achieve this?

The documentation is everything but clear to me on how to do it: https://get.foundation/sites/docs/drilldown-menu.html#_back

```
$('#element').foundation('_back', $elem);
```

What is `#element` and what is `$elem` in this context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the time being I created an (ugly) workaround:

I let foundation render the default back button but I hide it via css.
My custom back button then triggers that button's event:

```
$('.drilldown .back').on('click', function(){
    $(this).closest('.submenu').find('.js-drilldown-back > a')[0].click();
});
```

Not great, not terrible.